# Cry and cried - drop the y and add ied

Tags: meaning, grammar

I understand the usage of the two, but I'm looking for how to describe these types and rules for when you drop y and add ied. If that makes sense

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/verb_forms_and_tenses08.html

Comment: Don't most verbs that end in *y* perform in that way?  A verb like *to array* doesn't - *arrayed on the ground were...*. Could that be to do with the fact that the *y* is preceded by a vowel? *Annoy* - *annoyed*; *employ* - *employed* etc.

Comment: Good Q, may not be new, though. Please let us know of your background research effort.

Comment: http://www.usingenglish.com/articles/spelling-nouns-verbs-ending-y.html Maybe also: http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/english-spelling-rules/words-ending-in-y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[speakspeak](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/english-spelling-rules/words-ending-in-y)

> To form the past tense of regular verbs which end in -y

or [Dave's ESL Cafe](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/verb_forms_and_tenses08.html)

> Change -y to -i and add -ed.
>   This happens when a verb ends in a ***consonant*
>   and *y***

could be assistance to you. Check it out.

Comment: although you did just the exact opposite of what you wanted me to do, I'll edit the answer, then you cn upvote it :)

Comment: The difference is that I left a comment, not an answer. and my link was to an internal resource which may be considered stable in the context of the site, but thank you for the edit.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks for explaining it all to me :) Much appreciated!!

Comment: "To form the past tense...." doesn't explain anything. Why don't you summarise the tips/explanation from the first website? Links can rot and become obsolete, which means that  answers on EL&U should be self contained,